# Facing slowness in database server after migrating from SSMS 2008 to SSMS 2016

Tags: sql-server

We have a RDP server which is running in 2008 version of SSMS and OS. Recently we migrated this server to 2016 version, both the OS(2016) and SSMS(2016).
The configured new machine(with ssms2016) is same to the old one(with ssms2008) in terms of system configuration. It has a 64-bit OS with x64-based processor. RAM memory is 64.0 GB and 2.39 GHz (32 processor).
We are facing severe performance issue while running stored procedures in SSMS 2016 version, as the same code base has been migrated from sql server 2008.We are loading data to these servers using SSIS ETL tools.

For example if we are running a stored procedure in old server(with ssms2008) it is taking 1 hour of time to complete the execution but the same SP is taking 10 hours of time in new server(with ssms 2016) sometimes even more.
To identify the root cause we have tried below approaches but so far nothing worked.
•   After migration we changed the compatibility level of sql server from 2008 to 2016.
•   Restored the database once again from old server (ssms 2008) to new server (ssms 2016 ) without changing the compatibility level.
•   Recompiled the stored procedures in new server(ssms2016).
•   updated the statistics in new server(ssms2016).
•   Done the disc reconfiguration/thickening of windows new server drives also.
•   While running time consuming stored procedures in new server(ssms2016), parallely ran sql server
profiler to identify the issue, but couldn't find anything
•   Ran parallelly same query in ssms 2008 and ssms 2016 servers at the same time, in old
server(ssms2008) execution got completed much faster than new server(ssms2016)

Note: Is there any solution we can try to get the same execution time in both servers.

Thanks in Advance

Bala Muraleedharan

Comment: Updating your version of SSMS would have no impact on how long the instance takes to run a query. SSMS is just an IDE. The fact that you *were* using SSMS 2008 implies you are using SQL Server 2008 (or prior) as well, as SSMS 2008 supports SQL Server 2000-2008R2 iirc (SSMS 2016 supports SQL Server 2008-2016). SQL Server 2008, and older, are all end of life now and you should be looking at upgrade paths ASAP.

Comment: Search/replace your question text with "ssms"-->"SQL Server " and it will be clearer. Capture the execution plans of the old and new server queries, upload to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/), and add those links to your question.

Comment: Go read the documentation about compatibility level - it is not intended for production use and it is not a complete and exact "simulation" of the older version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume the SQL server version got updated too, as SSMS version would not make any difference.

It's impossible to tell of course, but query execution times can be drastically effected by the use of the new cardinality estimator in SQL Server 2014 and above.  99% of the time, things run faster, but once in a while, the new CE gets crushed.  Add this line to the stored procedure to run with the old 2008 CE and see if it makes any difference.

```
OPTION(QUERYTRACEON 9481);
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem may have two reasons:

1- Control the setting of your SQL server. Specifically limit maximum server memory to 60% of your RAM and increase the number of your tempdb(system database) files to reach to your CPU cores number.

2- Check your SP syntax. If you are using table type variable(@Table) change them to temp table(#Table).